# How to execute an .exe from outside its folder

Tags: c#, .net, console

The title of this question is not clear as it should.
What I mean is: I have a console application made by me which create some folders and files at the current Project. However, to get this app console running I must open the run window and put the file path where the .exe file is and execute it.

I'd like to know if there is a way of exec the .exe file through cmd without the need of going to its containing folder?

Comment: So you want to do "something.exe" instead of "C:\users\user\documents\something.exe"? On Windows you can add your path to the system %PATH%.

Comment: yes, that's what I want to do.

Comment: As @JohnnyMopp wrote, add the path to the system variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are searching for *How to modify the search path*. The search path is a set of directories used to search for executable files.

So for your case you could add your folder to the search path by using the [`PATH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/path) command in the command shell like

```
C:\>PATH C:\pathToYourApp;%PATH%
```

This would insert the specified directory (in this case *pathToYourApp*) at the start of the set of directories to be serached. (Inserted because `%PATH%` contains the original "path")